# How to center a div generated dynamically?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I generate a div for my [javascript automated validation script](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2009/09/08/cvalidate/). It is generated with below code:

```
var alertbox = document.createElement("div");
```

Now how do i center that div programatically both horizontally and vertically?

Note: Currently I am showing an alert box but once i know how to center a div, i will
replace the alertbox with this dynamically generated div which will also provide some
lightbox-like effect.

Thanks

Note: For reference, you can download latest version of this script [here](http://www.box.net/shared/4p1hesbdp4).

Please note that i dont want to use external css for this because this is validation script and it should be able to do it programatically. For example:
using something like this can be helpful:

```
 alertbox.style.position: whatever
 ....
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a matter of applying the same CSS rules as you would have with static content. Horizontal centering can be achieved as described in [this article](http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/center-div-block.shtml) - basically you give the div a fixed with and set left and right margins to `auto`. Vertical centering is a bit trickier - a few approaches are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css) and detailed in this [this blog post](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/).

The tidiest way is probably to define a CSS class that takes care of the centering and then apply that class to the dynamically generated element like this:

```
alertbox.className = "myCssClass";
```

**Update:**
Since you are already using JavaScript for creating the div, you could of course use it for the centering as well (in combination with CSS absolute positioning) - that would actually probably be a cleaner solution (due to the hackishness of the CSS vertical centering). Exactly how you do this depends a bit on what tools you are using - it's probably much easier to achieve with a JS framework such as Prototype or jQuery than with "raw" JavaScript since browsers handle window/browser heights a bit differently.

Comment: actually i dont want to use external css class, i should be able to do it programatically as i said in my question. thanks

Comment: Another example of vertical alignment using CSS + javascript: http://www.alistapart.com/d/footers/footer_variation1.html (view source)

Comment: Updated my answer to mention the pure Javascript approach. I think that would actually be the best solution in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, why not use the [validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)?

You should be able to combine it with a modal window (like [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)).

But if you don't want to change what you have already done, try something like this:

I would just apply some CSS rules to the div to position it (I've included an overlay which covers up the page and puts the alertbox on top):

***Note***: The reason the div is positioned to the far left is because you need to get the dimensions of the div with the contents inside. A hidden div will have a height and width of zero. Once the size is determined, it calculates the center of the page and positions the div.

CSS

```
#overlay {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background: #000;
 opacity: 0.8;
 filter: alpha(opacity=80);
 z-index: 100;
}
#alertbox {
 background: #444;
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 left: -99999px;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 101;
}
```

Script

```
function alertBox(alertMsg){
 // Add overlay
 $('<div id="overlay"></div>')
  .hide()
  .appendTo('body')
  .fadeIn('slow');
// Add alert
 $('<div id="alertbox"></div>')
  .html(alertMsg)
  .appendTo('body');
// calculate & position alertbox in center of viewport
 var abx = $('#alertbox');
 var abxTop = ($(window).height() - abx.height())/2;
 var abxLft = ($(window).width() - abx.width())/2;
 abx
  .hide()
  .css({ top: abxTop, left: abxLft })
  .fadeIn('slow');
// add click to hide alertbox & overlay
  $('#overlay, #alertbox').click(function(){
   $('#overlay, #alertbox').fadeOut('slow',function(){
     $('#alertbox').remove();
     $('#overlay').remove();
   });
  })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For whatever reason, I have not been able to center a `DIV` using `margin-right` and `margin-left`.  What I have found works better is to encapsulate them within a table (it's a bit globby code, but it works for me).  And you can use the DOM style object to modify the margin as follows:

`<table style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"><tr><td><div id="yourdiv"></div></td></tr></table>`

Comment: There are many examples out there for how to center DIVs without resorting to tables.  margin: 0 auto; works wonders, though you may have to put an additional container around it or style the parent container (body, html).